Porque el ZoomDrawerController no responde cuando ejecutó funciones asíncronas como el inicio y cierre de sesión?
Lo que pasa es que al iniciar sesión me redirige al Home Screen y de repente el sidebar no abre. Solo me pasa cuando inicio y cierro sesión. Para que se arregle debo reiniciar el servidor local de la app pero no es la idea.
Los demás botones de mi sidebar es para navegar en diferentes secciones osea no se maneja la asíncrona en la mayoría de los botones.
Mi proyecto esta hecho con Flutter

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
